# Images in a slick carousel don't appear first time

Tags: jquery, css, laravel, carousel, slick.js

The problem is that my slick carousel doesn't show selected image on page load. To display image you have to select from images navigation or arrows otherwise its empty. It's really strange, it should work like that by default, I have no error in the console. Here is how I call it:

```
<body>
    <div class="slider position-relative" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <div class='slider-for'>
         <img src="{{asset('images/publications/cassettes/Djalma_front.jpg')}}" alt="">
         <img src="{{asset('images/publications/cassettes/Djalma_back.jpg')}}" alt="">
         <img src="{{asset('images/publications/cassettes/Djalma_inside_2.jpg')}}" alt="">
        </div>
                            
        <div class="slider-nav">
         <img src="{{asset('images/publications/cassettes/Djalma_front.jpg')}}" alt="">
         <img src="{{asset('images/publications/cassettes/Djalma_back.jpg')}}" alt="">
         <img src="{{asset('images/publications/cassettes/Djalma_inside_2.jpg')}}" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $('.slider-for').slick({
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          arrows: true,
          speed: 300,
          fade: true,
          infinite: true,
          asNavFor: '.slider-nav'
        });
        $('.slider-nav').slick({
          slidesToShow: 3,
          slidesToScroll: 1,
          asNavFor: '.slider-for',
          infinite: true,
          focusOnSelect: true
        });
    
    </script>
</body>
```

And here you can see visualisation of the problem https://prnt.sc/17neizt . Here if I click on the images below it's going to work but its not showing at the beginning

Comment: maybe it is rtl and ltr problem check that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve my problem, it was really stupid mistake. The carousel was showing in a modal which i call in a function. The problem was that i called my slick outside of that function and it gets messed up. When i place slick in the function where I call that modal it started to work perfectly. Thanks for the help anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try with window.load function. Please see code below.

```
<body>
    <div class="slider position-relative" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <div class='slider-for'>
         <img src="{{asset('images/publications/cassettes/Djalma_front.jpg')}}" alt="">
         <img src="{{asset('images/publications/cassettes/Djalma_back.jpg')}}" alt="">
         <img src="{{asset('images/publications/cassettes/Djalma_inside_2.jpg')}}" alt="">
        </div>
                            
        <div class="slider-nav">
         <img src="{{asset('images/publications/cassettes/Djalma_front.jpg')}}" alt="">
         <img src="{{asset('images/publications/cassettes/Djalma_back.jpg')}}" alt="">
         <img src="{{asset('images/publications/cassettes/Djalma_inside_2.jpg')}}" alt="">
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        $(window).on('load',function(){
            setTimeout(function(){
                $('.slider-for').slick({
                  slidesToShow: 1,
                  slidesToScroll: 1,
                  arrows: true,
                  speed: 300,
                  fade: true,
                  infinite: true,
                  asNavFor: '.slider-nav'
                });
                $('.slider-nav').slick({
                  slidesToShow: 3,
                  slidesToScroll: 1,
                  asNavFor: '.slider-for',
                  infinite: true,
                  focusOnSelect: true
                });
            },1000);
            
        });
        
    
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when I try this I get this error: https://prnt.sc/17nimwo publications.js is where is the script

Comment: I have updated my code with $(window).load to $(window).on('load'). Please check whether it works?

Comment: The error is fixed but the problem with not showing image is still there.

Comment: In that case use delay function setTimeout. I have updated my code, please check and share your review.

Comment: Nothing has changed, the strange thing is that when I resize window, switch between resolutions from Inspect for example, the image it's showing, it's like image get refresh or something, but its not due to resolution for sure

Comment: Can you please share your file on info@shrijisolutions.com
I will check and update you soon.